# jquery colorbox will not close in iOS

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using colorbox on a web app for iOS Safari, and I've encountered a problem. When the colorbox is displayed, if you drag the site up and down a couple times (to initiate the iOS rubberbanding effect), the colorbox instance jumps a little, and then will no longer close.

I've been messing with this for too long, and still haven't come up with a satisfactory solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to help you without any code.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if you are using a newer jQuery-version (> 1.8.3).

I came across the same issue and found a bug report on jquery.com.
Zooming or moving around an opened colorbox on iOS devices like iPad seems to affect javascript-events, thus closing using JS, too:

> In particular, there is an event that clears the fxNow variable that gets lost. Since the event handler never runs, then the fxNow variable never gets cleared, so it stays at the same value forever, so the jQuery animation thinks that time has stopped. The result is that jQuery spins in a busy loop, and every time it checks the clock it calculates that the time has not changed, so the animation should not advance.

(http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12837)